# two hashing md5 code not return same result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, md5

I have two pieces of code to generate a password, both of which use the md5 hashing algorithm. The problem I have is that these two, despite being a hashing algorithm
They use but their output is not the same. Both return a string 32 characters long, but the result first is lowercase and the second is UPPERCASE.
What makes the difference? And how can passwords generated by Method 2 be converted to Method 1?

Method 1:

```
public static string ConvertToMD5Hash(this string password)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                var result = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
                return result.ToHex(false);
            }
        }
```

Method 2:

```
FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "MD5");
```

UPDATE:

```
result method 1: 93db94704e31b49b44452ddb5fcada2c

result method 2: 02EF13AE7287E27CF74D5E3F42A7FCB2
```

Comment: @CodeCaster: Of Course I'm right!!!

Comment: @CodeCaster : The OP asked What is the difference.  If using a different encoding works then the encoding is changing the Case of the letters.

Answer (score 3):

A hexadecimal representation is case-insensitive ("1A" == "1a"). Consider which representation you want, either lowercase or uppercase, and convert the other to that representation, or make the comparison itself case-insensitive.

As for the difference in actual hash contents, your problem lies here:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password)
```

You should not use ASCII encoding, as this will yield "?" for every input character above code point 127, causing a different hash than when using the proper encoding.

`FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile()`, brilliant name by the way, [uses UTF-8](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/Security/FormsAuthentication.cs,76), so:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)
```

Also, using an MD5 hash for password storage is a practice from the 00's, and should not be used anymore. It is unsafe. Do not roll your own password hashing, especially not since you've tagged the question ASP.NET Core, just use [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) for authentication and credential storage.